# HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC3 that uses Action<T> as template: Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let me preface this by saying that perhaps there's a better way to do this, and Razor is lighting the way. In any case, I have an HTML helper that acts as a repeater of sorts, but after an arbitrary number of repeats, it inserts an alternate template. Most obvious use? Tables that start a new row after x cells. The helper looks like this:

```
public static void SeriesSplitter<T>(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<T> items, int itemsBeforeSplit, Action<T> template, Action seriesSplitter)
{
    if (items == null)
        return;
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % itemsBeforeSplit == 0)
            seriesSplitter();
        template(item);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And in a Webforms view, the usage looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <% Html.SeriesSplitter(Model.Photos, 4, photo => { %>
            <td><img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Thumbnail.ashx?id=" + photo.ID)%>" alt="<%=Html.Encode(photo.Title)%>" /></td>
    <% }, () => { %></tr><tr><% }); %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this case, you'd have a table that renders four cells, then starts a new row by using the alternate template (the row start and end tags). The problem is that I can't find a way to make this work in Razor. Using a lambda inside of a Razor view seems like a pretty weird construct.

What would you do?

Comment: I ended up just using some repeated logic in the three views where I had a need for this, which is less elegant, but I couldn't spend any more time trying to get Razor to work like the Webforms view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil actually had a good post that solves the problem here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `Func<object, HelperResult>` (though I'm doing this from memory so it might need tweaking):

```
public static void SeriesSplitter<T>(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                     IEnumerable<T> items,
                                     int itemsBeforeSplit,
                                     Func<object, HelperResult> template,
                                     Func<object, HelperResult> seriesSplitter) {
    //pretty  much same code here as before
}
```

Then you would call it like so

```
@Html.SeriesSplitter(Model.Items, 3, @<td>item.Id</td>, @:</td><td>
)
```

Just note that because of how Razor does tag balancing during parsing you need the new line after `@:</td><td>`

Comment: But where does "item" come from in the actual call?